# I actually need a Mac computer to make an iPhone "app"?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id, development

I just jumped through all Apple's hoops to finally make an "Apple ID" account to be able to read how to make and submit an "app" to them for the iPhone or macOS.

I've been led around in circles now, but what I can piece together from all these misleading webpages and alleged "download" links is that you actually need a Mac computer to develop the "app"? You cannot use a Windows PC, which I do? Is that really the case?

Because there is no way that I can afford an Apple computer. Even the cheapest *iPhone* is way beyond my means.

All I wanted was to create something like a NW.js application and make sure it runs in the screen dimensions/resolution of an iPhone and then submit that. But that cannot be done? I actually need a Mac?

Comment: We strongly prefer one question per question. If you want to ask about building against one SDK, platform we might consider reopening or changing the close link.